# How to detect Gitpod workspace in Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, dotfiles, gitpod

So, I'm tweaking my dotfiles to automatically install packages and I want to automatically detect whether the installation script is being ran in a [Gitpod](https://gitpod.io) workspace. This is what I have at the moment:

```
if is-executable "gp"; then
    echo "Gitpod detected, not installing <pre-installed package>"
else
    # Continue with installation... rest of code goes here
fi
```

I know that `gp` is a command available in Gitpod due to it's CLI and the code above works fine, but it isn't really ideal, assuming that other packages also have the `gp` command outside of Gitpod (although I don't use them). So, what would be a better way to detect if a Bash script is being ran in Gitpod?

Comment: Can you skip the Gitpod check and instead check if the package you're about to install is already installed? That would express your intent better and be less brittle.

Comment: I was thinking about checking Gitpod so I can automatically rule out packages that are already installed on Gitpod, but for this single scenario, I guess checking if the package is installed would be fine. What about if I needed the Gitpod CLI specifically to run certain commands and I needed to check if it was a Gitpod workspace?

Comment: What dot files? Your shell configuration files?  Installing packages is something you should do at the *same time* as installing your dot files, not something you should need to repeatedly check for every time a shell starts. (Why check if `gp` is available when you only expect it to be unavailable *once*, instead of just installing it when you know it will be needed later?)

Comment: Forgot to clarify, this is the installation script of my dotfiles, as in `install.sh`. And yes, I mean shell configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function from the snippet [here](https://github.com/axonasif/dotsh/blob/4d641b3b42a8fc7614f7370d5d07218df1f2e069/src/utils/common.sh#L15):

```bash
function is::gitpod() {
      # Check for existence of this gitpod-specific file and the ENV var.
      test -e /ide/bin/gitpod-code && test -v GITPOD_REPO_ROOT;
}
```

Also, if you're interested, check out [dotsh](https://github.com/axonasif/dotsh/), it's already doing what you're trying to do here and even more!